# Unity 2D launch gameObject at a specific angle without affecting speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am working on a game where i need to shoot the ball at an angle and power defined by 2 sliders (1 angle slider, 1 power slider). I currently have this code to control the launching of the ball:

```
  public void shoot()
{
    float angle = angleSlider.GetComponent<Slider>().value;
    float power = powerSlider.GetComponent<Slider>().value;

    gameObject.SetActive(false);

    ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = true;

    Vector2 releaseVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, transform.up) * transform.forward;
    ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = releaseVector * (power/3);


}
```

with this current code it works almost perfect apart from one thing. When the angle is like between 30 and 60, the ball is launched well but if i set it to 0 degrees the ball would barely move and on the contrary if i set it to 90 degrees, the ball launches with much more power. How can i set a constant speed for all degrees so that the speed is only affected by the power slider only please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you shouldn't set the `velocity` of a rigidbody directly. Per the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)...

> In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly, as this can result in unrealistic behaviour.

Instead, you usually want to impart a physical impulse to the ball using an API like [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) or [AddRelativeForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html)

Comment: Fixed . Thanks!

Comment: @JohnWick if this answered your question, please select it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

That is easy.. You have to normalize the releaseVector.

```
  ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = releaseVector.normalized * (power/3);
```

Then adjust the power to what you want. That way you will have the direction u wanted and speed depends on the power value.

If you want to know what normalize do, you can find more information here;
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Normalize.html